# In dictionary where keys are numbers, how to find key which is smaller but the most near to given number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In dictionary where keys are numbers, how to find key which is smaller then a given number  but the most near to given number ?

I can sort list of keys in ascending and then while but is there more python way to do this ( I am from Java and this is Java approach)

```
example:
{{1:9}, {6:7}, {5:45}, {3:90}}
for given number 4 result is 3
```

Comment: Dictionary should look like `{1: 9, 3: 90, 5: 45, 6: 7}`.

Comment: @nakedfanatic why? because dict is unordered collection na? This there any thin I am missing?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The problem was all of the extra {braces} in the original question. The syntax in the original question will attempt to create a set (not a dict) containing four separate dictionaries as its elements. This will fail because dictionary is an unhashable type (can't be used as a set element or a dictionary key).

Comment: @nakedfanatic Understood. additional thanks to informal that set elements should be *hashable*, So similarly `a_set = {[1, 2], [3, 'a']}` will fail because lists are also unhashable type. Am I correct? Additionally I understand that dictionary key should be hashable type but Why this constraint imposed on set. -- Any short answer or link?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Dictionaries and sets are both a kind of hash table. It may help to think of a set as really just a "keys only" dictionary. Yes you are correct that lists are also unhashable.

Comment: @nakedfanatic Got it now perfectly ..Thanks very you much Nakedefanatic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think a variation of Vicktor Kerkez's response is clearest:

```
d = {1:9, 6:7, 5:45, 3:90}
print max(k for k in d if k < 4)
```

The `k for k in d if k < 4` part iterates over the keys and returns only those that are less than 4.  Then the `max()` returns the largest of those.

Comment: This is also at least one O faster than using a sort key with a custom lambda penalty function (on my machine).